# How do I learn recipes?

Tags: littlewood

I have unlocked the Tavern in Littlewood, and I discovered one recipe just by trial and error, but honestly, that's going to take forever if that's the only way for me to learn to cook.

Are there other ways to learn to cook other than me just randomly trying combinations? Failing that, is there a list of recipes somewhere?

Answer (score -1):

I've never played the game, but there's a pretty comprehensive Wiki for it.

[Main Wiki](https://littlewood.gamepedia.com/Littlewood)

I would include a list of the recipes to prevent link rot, but 1) I don't see this link rotting without the game dying, 2) All the recipes are listed in a grid with pictures.

[Cooking Wiki](https://littlewood.gamepedia.com/Cooking)